# Control elements individually in react-spring?

Tags: reactjs, animation, css-transforms, react-spring

I have a react component that renders a "conveyer" using `react-spring` [useTransition](https://react-spring.dev/docs/components/use-transition).  Essentially, I keep track of an array of data that grows like this:

```
[]
[1]
[2, 1]  // unshift
[3, 2, 1]
[4, 3, 2, 1]
[5, 4, 3, 2]
[6, 5, 4, 3] // never gets longer
...
```

The transitions are defined here:

```
  const transitions = useTransition(data, {
    from: { transform: 'translateY(-400%)' },
    enter: { transform: 'translateY(0%)' },
    leave: { transform: 'translateY(-400%)' },
    onRest: handleTransitionRest,
    config: (item, index, state) => {
      return {
        ...config.wobbly,
        bounce: state === 'enter' ? 2 : 0,
      };
    },
  });
```

The entering and exiting animations work fine, but there is no transition from left to right as the elements "progress" down the conveyer belt.  This is because the items are in a flex box, and jump to their new location as soon as the new element is rendered to the DOM.

I would like to additionally animate the `x` transitions.  I'm wondering if this is possible with `react-spring`.

My initial thought was to use `useTransition` again, but I don't think that's the appropriate hook - I don't believe it animates elements unless they are `enter`ing or `leave`ing.

I thought to use [useSprings](https://react-spring.dev/docs/components/use-springs), and to programmatically determine `from` and `to`:

```
  from: { transform: `translate3d(${80 * springIdx}px, 0, 0)` }
  to: { transform: `translate3d(${80 * (springIdx + 1)}px, 0, 0)` };
```

So for example, the 2nd element in the array would animate horizontally from 160px to 240px, whereas the 3rd element would animate horizontally from 240px to 320px.

This doesn't quite work, though, because the `springIdx` argument to `useSprings` is simply a `number` representing which `spring` we are working with (I think), rather than, say, the index of the element onto which this spring will be affixed.

I've also tried manually creating 6 springs, each representing a "stage" of the animation (enter, convey, convey, convey, convey, leave):

```
const ConveyerSmooth: React.FC = () => {
  const spring1 = useSpring({
    from: { transform: 'translate3d(0, -400%, 0)' },
    to: { transform: 'translate3d(0, 0, 0)' },
    config: { ...config.wobbly, bounce: 2 },
  });
  const spring2 = useSpring({
    from: { transform: 'translate3d(0, 0, 0)' },
    to: { transform: 'translate3d(100px, 0, 0)' },
    config: config.wobbly,
  });
  const spring3 = useSpring({
    from: { transform: 'translate3d(100px, 0, 0)' },
    to: { transform: 'translate3d(200px, 0, 0)' },
    config: config.wobbly,
  });
  const spring4 = useSpring({
    from: { transform: 'translate3d(200px, 0, 0)' },
    to: { transform: 'translate3d(300px, 0, 0)' },
    config: config.wobbly,
  });
  const spring5 = useSpring({
    from: { transform: 'translate3d(300px, 0, 0)' },
    to: { transform: 'translate3d(400px, 0, 0)' },
    config: { ...config.wobbly, bounce: 2 },
  });
  const spring6 = useSpring({
    from: { transform: 'translate3d(400px, 0, 0)' },
    to: { transform: 'translate3d(400px, -400%, 0)' },
    config: { ...config.wobbly, bounce: 2 },
  });
  const springs = [spring1, spring2, spring3, spring4, spring5, spring6];
  const [data, setData] = useState<number[]>([1]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const conveyerInterval = setInterval(() => {
      setData((prev) => {
        const newData = prev.slice(0, 5);
        newData.unshift(prev[0] + 1);
        return newData;
      });
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(conveyerInterval);
  }, []);

  return (
    <section className="pane conveyer">
      <section className="animation-window">
        {data.map((el, idx) => {
          return (
            <animated.div key={el} className="springy" style={springs[idx]}>
              {el}
            </animated.div>
          );
        })}
      </section>
      <section className="animation-info">OSHA violation.</section>
    </section>
  );
};
```

While this causes the boxes to enter, move, and leave, they don't actually *animate*.

At this point I'm wondering if this type of control - varying yet sequential springs on a variable set of data - is possible in `react-spring`.  I think I could create this effect for 1 object easy enough, something like

```
useSpring({
  from: { transform: 'translate3d(0, -400%, 0)' },
  to: [
    { transform: 'translate3d(0, 0, 0)' },
    { transform: 'translate3d(80px, 0, 0)' },
    { ... },
    { ... },
  ]
})
```

but once I start updating the contents of the data array it seems like each spring "starts over."

Any thoughts / suggestions welcome; thanks!